# Get Openshift to refresh the files when you update on github

Tags: github, openshift

How do you get openshift to refresh the files when you update on github? I created my app with openshift and it pulled from git hib ok.

Comment: i am also interested in this question. i don`t think cartridges available for this. All we need is post-receive service hook from github and do the rest. I found heroku deploy open source. See that to know some idea https://github.com/himynameisjonas/heroku-deployer/

Comment: @rajasimon did you ever figure out how to do this? I don't know Jenkins or ssh very well for Redhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use Jenkins and setup a web hook to notify Jenkins when you do a git push to github, and have it build & deploy your project.

Comment: I need node too, is there a cartridge for that I can use for node + jenkins?

Comment: When you create an application, you can enable jenkins, or you can add on the jenkins cartridge at any time.  Or you can install jenkins on it's own gear.

Comment: nice, I added the jenkins to it, but it points to ssh://mysite.rhcloud.com/~/git/space.git intead of github, is this all I need to change?

Comment: You need to setup a web hook on github that points to your jenkins instance, then you need to setup everything in jenkins to deploy how you want it.

Comment: any tutorials for this?